# Start Excel add-in with C#

Tags: c#, excel, add-in

Is it possible to start an Excel add-in (in my case statistiXL) and interact with it by using c#?
The add-in opens a frame with some fields, that also should be accessible with c#.

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you look at their [support site](http://www.statistixl.com/support/support.aspx)??

Comment: I thought there might be a general way of doing this..

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Excel Interop; be aware addins aren't loaded when starting Excel via interop so you need to do something like this:

```
var excel = new Application();
var workbook = excel.workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);
excel.RegisterXLL(pathToMyXll);
excel.ShowExcel();
```

[This example](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;270844) should get you going; it's in VB, but the interop object names and the concept are the same.